# JPA ManyToMany mapping issue(unable to map same entity to another)

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, many-to-many

I'm new to `jpa` and `spring-data`, so please forgive my ignorance on the matter.

I have two Entities, and I'm having trouble mapping them to each other with ManyToMany relationship:

**Department:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Department")
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer         id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String          name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "department_week_days", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "department_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "week_day_id"))
    private List<WeekDay>   weekDays;

    public Department(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        weekDays = new ArrayList<WeekDay>();
    }

    protected Department() {
    }

    public void addWeekDay(WeekDay day) {
        weekDays.add(day);
        day.getDepartments().add(this);
    }

    // omitted setters and getters 

}
```

and

**WeekDay:**

```
@Entity
public class WeekDay {

    public static enum WeekDays {

        MO("Monday", 1), TU("Tuesday", 2), WE("Wednesday", 3), TH("Thursday ", 4), FR("Friday", 5), SA("Saturday", 6), SU("Sunday", 7);

        private String  name;
        private int     dayNum;

        private WeekDays(String name, int dayNum) {
            this.name = name;
            this.dayNum = dayNum;
        }

        public int asInt() {
            return dayNum;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer             id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String              name;

    @Transient
    private int                 numericOrder;

    @Embedded
    private WorkingHours        workingHours;

    @Column(name = "minimumEmployees")
    private Integer             minimumEmployees;

    @Column(name = "maximumEmployees")
    private Integer             maximumEmployees;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "weekDays")
    private List<Department>    departments;

    public WeekDay(WeekDays day, WorkingHours workingHours, Integer minimumEmployees, Integer maximumEmployees) {

        this.name = day.toString();
        this.numericOrder = day.asInt();
        this.workingHours = workingHours;
        this.minimumEmployees = minimumEmployees;
        this.maximumEmployees = maximumEmployees;

        departments = new ArrayList<Department>();

    }

    protected WeekDay() {
    }

    // omitted setters and getters

}
```

My problem is that I can't add the same `WeekDay` to two different `Department`'s
for example:

```
WeekDay day = WeekDayFactory.create(WeekDayFactory.SA, WeekDayFactory.DAY_SHORT, 1, 2);

Department d1 = new Department("d1");
d1.addWeekDay(day);
repository.save(d1);

Department d2 = new Department("d2");
d2.addWeekDay(day);
repository.save(d2);
```

the above wont let me add `day` into `d2` **why?**

If I create a `new` `WeekDay` with the same values as `day` it works:

```
WeekDay day = WeekDayFactory.create(WeekDayFactory.SA, WeekDayFactory.DAY_SHORT, 1, 2);
WeekDay sameValuesAsDay = WeekDayFactory.create(WeekDayFactory.SA, WeekDayFactory.DAY_SHORT, 1, 2);

Department d1 = new Department("d1");
d1.addWeekDay(day);
repository.save(d1);

Department d2 = new Department("d2");
d2.addWeekDay(sameValuesAsDay);
repository.save(d2);
```

obviously this creates a duplicate row in the `WeekDay` table which defeats the purpose of `ManyToMany` mapping since I can just add the data into the `department` table it self for each `department`.

**As I said at the beginning, I have no real idea on how to do this correctly so please excuse my ignorance and point me in the right direction to solve my problem.**

**EDIT**

stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at com.kendaya.holidaysplaning.HolidaysPlaningApplication.main(HolidaysPlaningApplication.java:21) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.kendaya.holidaysplaning.entities.WeekDay; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.kendaya.holidaysplaning.entities.WeekDay
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:299) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.kendaya.holidaysplaning.HolidaysPlaningApplication.lambda$0(HolidaysPlaningApplication.java:39) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.kendaya.holidaysplaning.entities.WeekDay
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:765) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:456) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:775) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:508) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Comment: what's the exception you're getting when you say "it wont let me add `day` into `d2`"? post the stacktrace as well.

Comment: @Ish I was hoping that my problem was something trivial that I was doing wrong. I added the stacktrace... Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the mapping is correct and everything should work as expected. But the following error message

> Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.kendaya.holidaysplaning.entities.WeekDay

is telling you that your `day` instance is detached. Probably the first `repository.save()` call is executed in a separate transaction so that after `save()` call the persistence context is cleared. You have two options to solve the problem:

- Either reread the `day` record after the first `save` call before persisting the second department entity, or

  ```
  Department d2 = new Department("d2");
  WeekDay day1 = repository.find(day.getId()); //!!! pseodocode
  d2.addWeekDay(day1);
  repository.save(d2);
  ```
- execute both the `repository.save()` calls in the same transaction, in which case the `day` instance is still managed.

Comment: Many thanks, I needed to understand that! 
Problem now solved by:

`d1.addWeekDay(day);
d2.addWeekDay(day);
repository.save(Arrays.asList(d1, d2));`

Answer (score 0):

```
Department d1 = new Department("d1");
d1.addWeekDay(day);
repository.save(d1);

Department d2 = new Department("d2");
d2.addWeekDay(sameValuesAsDay);
repository.save(d2);
```

replace the code with

```
Department d1 = new Department("d1");
d1.addWeekDay(day);
d1 =repository.save(d1);

Department d2 = new Department("d2");
d2.addWeekDay(sameValuesAsDay);
d2 =repository.save(d2);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the accepted answer for this questions, [Detached entity passed to persist error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27672337/detached-entity-passed-to-persist-error) , will help you to understand what is the root cause.

In short, hibernate's save method accepts only transient object(i.e. object created with new operator). When you persist the object using save, that object is no more in the hibernate session (in your case day object) so it throws the error. Try using saveOrUpdate method or as suggested by ujulu, retrieve the day object and then persist.